# Error executing Get-AzFirewallPolicy command for a specific firewall policy

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I am trying to list azure firewall policies using Get-AzFirewallPolicy command, but running into mapping error when trying to obtain details of one of the firewall policies.

Following is the command execution:

```
Get-AzFirewallPolicy -Name "FirewallPolicy_AzureFirewall_EU_NonProd" -ResourceGroupName "RG-Firewalls-NonProd"
```

Following is the error message:

```
Get-AzFirewallPolicy : Error mapping types.
Mapping types:
FirewallPolicy -> PSAzureFirewallPolicy
Microsoft.Azure.Management.Network.Models.FirewallPolicy -> Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Network.Models.PSAzureFirewallPolicy
Type Map configuration:
FirewallPolicy -> PSAzureFirewallPolicy
Microsoft.Azure.Management.Network.Models.FirewallPolicy -> Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Network.Models.PSAzureFirewallPolicy
Property:
ThreatIntelWhitelist
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-AzFirewallPolicy -Name "FirewallPolicy_AzureFirewall_EU_NonProd ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzFirewallPolicy], AutoMapperMappingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Network.GetAzureFirewallPolicyCommand
```

I have tried updating my Az.Network(was 5.x now 7.x version) module, but no luck.

TIA

Comment: Try to install again  `Install-Module -Name Az -Force`

Answer (score 0):

can you check these, firstly make sure you are using the latest version of the Azure PowerShell module.

```html
Update-Module -Name Az -Force
```

and verify the API version used by the Get-AzFirewallPolicy command. You can use the -ApiVersion parameter to specify the API version explicitly.

```html
Get-AzFirewallPolicy -Name "FirewallPolicy_AzureFirewall_EU_NonProd" -ResourceGroupName "RG-Firewalls-NonProd" -ApiVersion '2020-05-01'
```

Comment: No, A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ApiVersion'. I have ensured that Az, Az.Network are updated.

Answer (score 0):

This error related to the mapping of types in the Azure PowerShell module try to use below command and `Install-Module -Name Az -Force`  it will update up to date Azure PowerShell module.

When I ran this PowerShell command, I got detail list of firewall policy like below:

```
$firewallPolicy = Get-AzFirewallPolicy -Name "FWNAME" -ResourceGroupName "RGName"
$firewallPolicy | Format-List *
```

***Output***:

```
Identity             : 
ThreatIntelMode      : Alert
ThreatIntelWhitelist : 
BasePolicy           : 
ProvisioningState    : Succeeded
RuleCollectionGroups : {/subscriptions/bxxxxxxxxb5ba-2b83xxxxxxf/resourceGroups/Networking-Resources/providers/Microsoft.Network/firewallPolicies/fw-test-pol/ruleCollectionGroups/DefaultAppl
                       icationRuleCollectionGroup, /subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxx-b5ba-2b8xxxxxxxf/resourceGroups/Networking-Resources/providers/Microsoft.Network/firewallPolicies/fw-test-pol/ruleC
                       ollectionGroups/DefaultNetworkRuleCollectionGroup, /subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxx5ba-2b8xxxxf/resourceGroups/Networking-Resources/providers/Microsoft.Network/firewallPol
                       icies/fw-test-pol/ruleCollectionGroups/DefaultDnatRuleCollectionGroup, /subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxx-b5ba-2b83a074c23f/resourceGroups/Networking-Resources/providers/Microsoft
                       .Network/firewallPolicies/fw-test-pol/ruleCollectionGroups/testgroup...}
DnsSettings          : 
SqlSetting           : 
IntrusionDetection   : 
TransportSecurity    : 
Sku                  : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Network.Models.PSAzureFirewallPolicySku
Snat                 : 
ExplicitProxy        : 
PrivateRange         : 
PrivateRangeText     : null
ResourceGroupName    : Networking-Resources
Location             : westus2
ResourceGuid         : 
Type                 : Microsoft.Network/FirewallPolicies
Tag                  : {CreatedBy, CreatedDate, OwningTeam, Reason}
TagsTable            : 
                       Name         Value                
                       ===========  =====================
                       CreatedBy    chnaykod             
                       CreatedDate  4/12/2022 10:17:31 PM
                       OwningTeam   Integration          
                       Reason       Repro                
                       
Name                 : fw-test-pol
Etag                 : 44XXXXXXXXXb0fe22
Id                   : /subscriptions/b83cXXXXXXX/resourcegroups/Networking-Resources/providers/Microsoft.Network/firewallPolicies/fw-test-pol
```

[image]

If still error persists, try updating the `Az.Network` module to the latest version using below command:

```
Update-Module -Name Az.Network
```